# Problems Installing choroplethrZip: "Command failed (1)"

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

So I have been hitting my head against the wall for a few days now trying to understand why my machine will not load choroplethrZip. I have tried the recommended installation pathway (with devtools and github) but I keep receiving the error message below:

```
#install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')
Downloading GitHub repo arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/arilamstein/choroplethrZip/zipball/v1.5.0
Installing choroplethrZip
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/dbrennan/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0q4jjY/devtools29fc168c68f5/arilamstein-choroplethrZip-3cbc9f3"  \
  --library="C:/Users/dbrennan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'choroplethrZip' ...
** R
** data
** inst
** tests
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'choroplethr' 2.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'choroplethrZip'
* removing 'C:/Users/dbrennan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/choroplethrZip'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

I have tried restarting r and running the code immediately, as well as restarting the computer itself. I have also tried to read the package zip file into R directly but that has not worked either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with this packages but the error makes me believe a dependent package ('choroplethr') is out of date. Can one manually load 'choroplethr'? Is there a reason an older version of 'choroplethr' is being loaded by default?

Comment: That was the problem! Awesome man, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Buried within the error message is this:

```
namespace 'choroplethr' 2.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
```

And in fact, if you look at the [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L17) page of choroplethrZip you will see that it imports "choroplethr (>= 3.3.0)".

Since you only have version 2.2.0 installed, I recommend typing:

```
update.packages()
```

which will update all your packages. Then try installing and loading choroplethrZip again.